# Python: Replacing embedded function within string with a different term

Tags: python, string

I have a bunch of equations (from Eviews) that I need to parse and transfer into another language. They're imported as strings, e.g.:

```
a = "series1=0.173*d(series1,0,1)+0.010*d(series2,0,2)"
```

The problem I'm having is replacing the embedded eviews functions in the equations. I need to find a way to transform the "d(series2,0,1)" Eviews function into a format readable in the other language. Specifically,

```
"d(series2,0,x)" --> "(series2 - series2(-x))"
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write a function that takes an equation string (like in the first line above), detects if the equation has a "d(series,0,x)" function in it, and then replaces it in the equation according to the example above. e.g.

```
a = "series1=0.173*d(series1,0,1)+0.010*d(series2,0,2)"

def function(a):
    blah blah

function(a) --> "series1=0.173*(series1 - series1(-1))+0.010*(series2 - series2(-2))"
```

Anyone have any idea how to get started?

Comment: so what have you written? we are not going to write specific parser for you from scratch

Comment: start with [tokenization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis))

Comment: This is the last piece of the parsing I have to figure out. Wasn't sure how to get started with it, and thought someone else might have an idea of where to start. Thanks for the recommendation that I start by tokenizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this without too much trouble using two standard tools: regular expressions and string formatting. If it's significantly more complex than your example, though, parsing via regexes could get ugly, and you might do better with a system that has a model of the formal structure of the parsed language.

For the first, you'll want to `import re`, and then craft a regex that matches the function string you're looking for and puts the variable parts into groups for extraction. Here is a simple one for the case you mention:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'd\((\w+),\d+,(\d+)\)')
>>> arg_sets = regex.findall(a)
>>> arg_sets
[('series1', '1'), ('series2', '2')]
```

[Here's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) the official documentation for python's regexes, and here's [a tool](https://regex101.com/) that can help you build them (there are others too, that was just the first one I found with a python mode).

Once you have the regex, you can use the results in a format string to get the output you want, like

```
>>> format_string = "({first} - {first}(-{third}))"
>>> format_string.format( **dict(zip(['first', 'third'], arg_sets[0])))
'(series1 - series1(-1))'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is super helpful.